# Graph-theoretic interpretation of determinant?

Tags: graph-theory, determinant

The permanent can be interpreted as the number of perfect matchings in bipartite graphs.

> Is there a similar graph-theoretic interpretation of the determinant?

Comment: Frank Harary has written an article about this: "Determinants, Permanents and Bipartite graphs" http://www.jstor.org/pss/2689132

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm aware of a few.  There is the [Lindström-Gessel-Viennot lemma](http://qchu.wordpress.com/2009/11/17/the-lindstrom-gessel-viennot-lemma/), and there is also the [matrix-tree theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_theorem).  If $A$ is the adjacency matrix of a finite graph $G$ then $\frac{1}{\det(I - At)}$ describes a kind of "zeta function" of $G$.  I describe some of how this works in [this blog post](http://qchu.wordpress.com/2009/11/04/newtons-sums-necklace-congruences-and-zeta-functions-ii/).

You may also be interested in Kuperberg's [An exploration of the permanent-determinant method](http://www.combinatorics.org/Volume_5/PDF/v5i1r46.pdf).